# Realtime Database getValue() can't convert object of type java.lang.String to my project model

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

The Realtime Database structure is as above. It is considered to be the current data.

```
override suspend fun registerNewUserId(userId: String) {

    database.child(USERS).child("vwijvekv").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            snapshot.children.map {
                item = it.getValue(ChatRoomItem::class.java)
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })
    database.child(USERS).child("adsvkjekv").setValue(item)
}
```

```
data class ChatRoomItem(
    val chatRoomId: String? = null,
    val chatMessage: String? = null
) {

    fun toMap(): Map<String, Any?> {
        return mapOf(
            "chatRoomId" to chatRoomId,
            "chatMessage" to chatMessage
        )
    }
}
```

As a result of execution, the following error occurs.

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.dreamixmlversion.ui.chat.model.ChatRoomItem

What's the problem?

It is possible to write to Firebase, and the data in the picture above is actually written by writing code.

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating the following reference:

```
database.child(USERS).child("vwijvekv")
```

And attach a listener to it, it means that you're reading everything under the `vwijvekv` node. As I see in your screenshot, this node contains two fields of type String, one is called `chatRoomId` and the one `chatMessage`. So when you iterate through the `snapshot` you cannot get objects of type `ChatRoomItem`, because there are only two strings there, hence the error.

If you want to map the `vwijvekv` node into an object of type `ChatRoomItem`, then you have to remove the loop. So the code should look like this:

```
override suspend fun registerNewUserId(userId: String) {

    database.child(USERS).child("vwijvekv").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            item = snapshot.getValue(ChatRoomItem::class.java)
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "${error.message}") //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    })
    database.child(USERS).child("adsvkjekv").setValue(item)
}
```

Comment: Hey yuji. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?